# SQL--finding top parent and bottom child values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a conundrum. The situation is that we have a table (OSCL). This table has a child table (SCL4) that links to more tables (ODLN -> DLN1).

The trick here, is that OSCL has an entry that links recursively back to itself (the "u_callParent" field will have a "CallID" in it that it corresponds to.)

Normally, there will be 0-3 levels of "Call Parents" that need to be linked back to in the query. However, once in a blue moon, there may be as many as 15 levels deep of parent calls.

The end goal of this query is a data set as follows:

```
DLN1.DocEntry |  ODLN.DocNum | DLN1.ItemCode | DLN1.StockPrice | 
DLN1.Quantity | DLN1.LineNum | most parental call id | most child close date
```

Here is a sample of my data that I'm working with.:

```
OSCL
--------------------------------------
CallID  | u_callParent | CloseDate   |
--------|-----------------------------
11638   | null         | 7/1/2016    |
11688   | 11638        | 7/3/2016    |
12548   | 11688        | 7/7/2016    |
12705   | 12548        | 7/8/2016    |
12845   | 12705        | 7/15/2016   |
13321   | 12845        | 7/18/2016   |
13643   | 13321        | 7/21/2016   | 
13661   | 13643        | 7/24/2016   |
13872   | 13661        | 7/29/2016   |
--------------------------------------

   ^
   |
   v

SCL4
------------------------
SrcvCallID  | DocAbs   |
------------|-----------
11638       | 7541     |
11688       | null     |
12548       | null     |
12705       | null     |
12845       | 8993     |
13321       | 9305     |
13643       | 9335     |
13661       | 9408     |
13872       | 10519    |
------------------------

                ^
               /
              /
             /
            /
           /
          v
ODLN
------------------------
DocEntry    | DocNum   |
------------|-----------
7541        | 9540     |
8993        | 10992    |
9305        | 11304    |
9335        | 11334    |
9408        | 11407    |
10519       | 12518    |
------------------------

   ^
   |
   v

DLN1
----------------------------------------------------
DocEntry    | ItemCode       | Quantity | LineNum  |
------------|---------------------------------------
7541        | 6LH06990000    | 1        | 0        |
7541        | 6LE49877000    | 1        | 1        |
8993        | 6LE09191000    | 1        | 0        |
8993        | 6LE09788000    | 1        | 1        |
8993        | 6LE09132000    | 1        | 2        |
8993        | 6LE09155000    | 1        | 3        |
8993        | C010814000     | 1        | 4        |
8993        | 6LH72649000    | 1        | 5        |
9305        | LaborDefault   | 2.113    | 0        |
9335        | LaborDefault   | 1        | 0        |
9408        | LaborDefault   | 1.131    | 0        |
10519       | LaborDefault   | 3.213    | 0        |
10519       | 6LA15184000    | 3        | 1        |
10519       | 6LE09604000    | 1        | 2        |
----------------------------------------------------

Goal Results
------------
DocEntry | DocNum | ItemCode  | Quantity | LineNum | CallID | CloseDate | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
7541     | 9540   | 6LH...    | 1        | 0       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
7541     | 9540   | 6LE4...   | 1        | 1       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
8993     | 10992  | 6LE0...   | 1        | 0       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
8993     | 10992  | etc...    | 1        | 1       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
8993     | 10992  |           | 1        | 2       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
8993     | 10992  |           | 1        | 3       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
8993     | 10992  |           | 1        | 4       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
8993     | 10992  |           | 1        | 5       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
9305     | 11304  |           | 2.113    | 0       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
9335     | 11334  |           | 1        | 0       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
9408     | 11407  |           | 1.131    | 0       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
10519    | 12518  |           | 3.213    | 0       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
10519    | 12518  |           | 3        | 1       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
10519    | 12518  |           | 1        | 2       | 11638  | 7/29/2016 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The arrows designate the links between the tables.

I wrote the following query that returned the right results; however, it took 1:57 to run for only 23 rows (with a limiter to originating call 11638). The issue is that I'll need to run it with a date range parameter in the where statement, and we don't want to wait for 2+ minutes every time we re-run this query.

```
select s1.*
, max(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(child15.callid, child14.callid),child13.callid),child12.callid),child11.callid),child10.callid),child9.callid),child8.callid),child7.callid),child6.callid),child5.callid),child4.callid),child3.callid),child2.callid),child1.callid),oscl.callID)) MinCallID

 FROM (
select odln.docentry
, odln.docnum
, dln1.itemcode
, dln1.Quantity
, dln1.LineNum
, min(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(parent15.callid, parent14.callid),parent13.callid),parent12.callid),parent11.callid),parent10.callid),parent9.callid),parent8.callid),parent7.callid),parent6.callid),parent5.callid),parent4.callid),parent3.callid),parent2.callid),parent1.callid),oscl.callID)) MinCallID

 from SCL4 
inner join odln on odln.DocEntry = scl4.DocAbs
left join dln1 on dln1.DocEntry = odln.DocEntry
left join oscl on oscl.callid = scl4.SrcvCallID
left join oscl parent1 on oscl.U_callParent = parent1.callID
left join oscl parent2 on parent1.U_callParent = parent2.callID
left join oscl parent3 on parent2.U_callParent = parent3.callID
left join oscl parent4 on parent3.U_callParent = parent4.callID
left join oscl parent5 on parent4.U_callParent = parent5.callID
left join oscl parent6 on parent5.U_callParent = parent6.callID
left join oscl parent7 on parent6.U_callParent = parent7.callID
left join oscl parent8 on parent7.U_callParent = parent8.callID
left join oscl parent9 on parent8.U_callParent = parent9.callID
left join oscl parent10 on parent9.U_callParent = parent10.callID
left join oscl parent11 on parent10.U_callParent = parent11.callID
left join oscl parent12 on parent11.U_callParent = parent12.callID
left join oscl parent13 on parent12.U_callParent = parent13.callid  
left join oscl parent14 on parent13.U_callParent = parent14.callID
left join oscl parent15 on parent14.U_callParent = parent15.callID



group by odln.docentry
, odln.docnum
, dln1.itemcode
, dln1.Quantity
, dln1.LineNum

) s1
left join oscl on oscl.callid = s1.MinCallID
left join oscl child1 on child1.U_callParent = oscl.callID
left join oscl child2 on child2.U_callParent = child1.callID
left join oscl child3 on child3.U_callParent = child2.callID
left join oscl child4 on child4.U_callParent = child3.callID
left join oscl child5 on child5.U_callParent = child4.callID
left join oscl child6 on child6.U_callParent = child5.callID
left join oscl child7 on child7.U_callParent = child6.callID
left join oscl child8 on child8.U_callParent = child7.callID
left join oscl child9 on child9.U_callParent = child8.callID
left join oscl child10 on child10.U_callParent = child9.callID
left join oscl child11 on child11.U_callParent = child10.callID
left join oscl child12 on child12.U_callParent = child11.callID
left join oscl child13 on child13.U_callParent = child12.callid 
left join oscl child14 on child14.U_callParent = child13.callID
left join oscl child15 on child15.U_callParent = child14.callID

--where MinCallID = 11638

group by s1.docentry
, s1.docnum
, s1.itemcode
, s1.stockprice
, s1.Quantity
, s1.LineNum
, s1.MinCallID

order by s1.mincallid, docentry, LineNum
```

I know that it's a bit ham-fisted, and there's got to be a better way to write it, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I also cannot add any modifications to the database tables (so I can't add a field saying "originating call" or anything).

For what it's worth, the tables are all based in SAP Business One with a UDF for u_callParent on OSCL.

EDIT:

Based on the comments below, I've updated the query to look like this:

```
with cte as (

                SELECT
                    OSCL.CallID
                    , OSCL.U_callParent
                    , PLevel = 0
                    , TopParent = CallID
                FROM OSCL
                WHERE U_callParent is null

                UNION ALL

                SELECT 
                    OSCL.CallID
                    , OSCL.U_callParent
                    , PLevel = cte.Plevel + 1
                    , cte.TopParent
                FROM OSCL
                INNER JOIN cte on oscl.U_callParent = cte.callID
)

SELECT 
cte.* , scl4.DocAbs, scl4.Object
FROM cte
left join scl4 on scl4.SrcvCallID = cte.callID
where TopParent = 11638
```

The issue is now that I need to get the OSCL.CloseDate for the "most childish" of the info, and I'm not sure of a good way to do that. Any thoughts?

---

Edit 2:

Alright, looks like I figured it out:

```
with cte as (

                SELECT
                    OSCL.CallID
                    , OSCL.U_callParent
                    , PLevel = 0
                    , TopParent = CallID
                FROM OSCL
                WHERE U_callParent is null

                UNION ALL

                SELECT 
                    OSCL.CallID
                    , OSCL.U_callParent
                    , PLevel = cte.Plevel + 1
                    , cte.TopParent
                FROM OSCL
                INNER JOIN cte on oscl.U_callParent = cte.callID
)

SELECT 
odln.docentry, odln.docnum, dln1.itemcode, dln1.quantity, dln1.linenum, cte.TopParent, child.closeDate
FROM cte
left join scl4 on scl4.SrcvCallID = cte.callID
left join (SELECT max(callid) callID, topParent from cte group by topParent) s1 on s1.TopParent = cte.TopParent
inner join oscl Child on Child.callID = s1.callID
left join odln on odln.ObjType = scl4.Object and odln.DocEntry = scl4.DocAbs
left join dln1 on dln1.DocEntry = odln.DocEntry
where cte.TopParent = 11638
```

If there's a better way than using the subquery in my last select statement, please let me know, but this seems to be running quickly.

Comment: Sounds like you're potentially looking for a Recursive CTE http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/  I'd offer more help if I could... I've written a few throughout the years, but it still brains my hurt, and I immediately block out that portion of my life.

Comment: "... all based in SAP Business One with a UDF for". _You can't leave us hanging there!_ Yup, a recursive CTE is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll research and see if I can make my brain not hurt. ;)

Comment: Alright, I've got the recursive CTE working to pull the "parent ID" now. However, I still am unsure how that will help me to get the "most childish" close date. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind--looks like I figured it out! See above for what I ended up doing.

Comment: @phroureo you should post your solution as an answer rather than an edit to the question.  Once the question is old enough, you'll be able to accept your own answer as "the answer".

Comment: The `ISNULL` x 10+... In cases like that you should consider using [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) as it takes any number of parameters. But you seem to have found a soluation and as Kritner points out, you should post it as an answer not as an edit in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (

            SELECT
                OSCL.CallID
                , OSCL.U_callParent
                , PLevel = 0
                , TopParent = CallID
            FROM OSCL
            WHERE U_callParent is null

            UNION ALL

            SELECT 
                OSCL.CallID
                , OSCL.U_callParent
                , PLevel = cte.Plevel + 1
                , cte.TopParent
            FROM OSCL
            INNER JOIN cte on oscl.U_callParent = cte.callID
)

SELECT 
odln.docentry, odln.docnum, dln1.itemcode, dln1.quantity, dln1.linenum, cte.TopParent, child.closeDate
FROM cte
left join scl4 on scl4.SrcvCallID = cte.callID
left join (SELECT max(callid) callID, topParent from cte group by topParent) s1 on s1.TopParent = cte.TopParent
inner join oscl Child on Child.callID = s1.callID
left join odln on odln.ObjType = scl4.Object and odln.DocEntry = scl4.DocAbs
left join dln1 on dln1.DocEntry = odln.DocEntry
where cte.TopParent = 11638
```

Here's the solution that I found that ended up working.